# How to provide custom exception message for an exception thrown by extension function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following Kotlin code:

```kotlin
fun getAdminUser(): User {
    return getAllUsers().first { it.userType == ADMIN } as User
}
```

If `getAllUsers()` doesn't have an element that matches the specified predicate, it throws a `NoSuchElementException`. I'm happy with this exception but would like to override the exception message to provide more context when it fails. Is it possible to do in Kotlin w/o `try-catch`?

Comment: `getAllUsers().firstOrNull { it.userType == ADMIN } ?: throw NoSuchElementException("my custom exception message")`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, it doesn't work with the casting I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `firstOrNull` function to achieve that.

```
fun getAdminUser(): User {
    return (getAllUsers().firstOrNull { it.userType == ADMIN } as? User) ?: throw NoSuchElementException("Element not found")
}
```

Comment: That solved my issue. And there's no need in wrapping the part before the Elvis operator in round brackets. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [firstOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) to get first element or have null and use the elvis operator to throw `NoSuchElementException`.

```kotlin
fun getAdminUser(): User {
    val user = getAllUsers().firstOrNull { it.userType == ADMIN } ?: throw NoSuchElementException("My custom exception message")
    return user as? User ?: IllegalStateException("The element was neither null nor an instance of User class")
}
```

Otherwise to do it in single line you can do something like this:

```kotlin
fun getAdminUser(): User {
    return getAllUsers().firstOrNull { it.userType == ADMIN }?.also { require(it is User) { "The element was neither null nor an instance of User class" } } ?: throw NoSuchElementException("My custom exception message")
}
```